# Why string parameter is clear when using the lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda

```cpp
auto Function(char dat[]) {
    return [&]() {cout << dat << " <- char*\n"; };
}

auto FunctionSub(string dat) {
    return [&]() {cout << dat << " <- string\n"; };
}

int main() {
    auto f = Function((char*)"HI1");
    auto f_sub = FunctionSub(string("HI2"));
    f();
    f_sub();
    return 0;
}
```

The two functions Function and FunctionSub return similar lambda functions.
However, the different thing is only the type of parameter (string and char*).

I thought both HI1 and HI2 will be printed.
But when I execute it, HI1 is printed successfully, and HI2 is not printed.

I don't know why HI2 is not printed.

Comment: Change the ampersands  to an `=` sign and try again. Then, check `cppreference.com` to see if you can find out what changed. Your compiler is probably emititing some warnings too. Don't ever ignore them.

Comment: Undefined behavior as you're capturing local variable by reference and then using that reference. To solve this replace `&` with `=`.

Comment: I think `Function` has the same issue, but undefined behavior means anything can happen, it can also appear to work

Comment: Both functions are indeed UB.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/hx1K4Gbfc vs https://godbolt.org/z/h5b5rMrP6